# CrossConnectivity throws an exception

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to check **wifi** connectivity on the mobile device in the PCL, and I have used the `CrossConnectivity` plugin, but the following code is throwing an exception (null exception, no description).

```
bool isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

**ViewModel.cs**

```
using Plugin.Connectivity;

private async Task Connection()
{
  Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<proto>\w+)://[^/]+?:(?<port>\d+)?/",
  RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
  Match m = r.Match(serviceURL);

  try
  {
    if (m.Success)
    {
      Int32.Parse(r.Match(serviceURL).Result("${port}"));
      Uri myUri = new Uri(serviceURL);
      string host = myUri.Host;
      bool isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ConnectionError = ex.GetUserMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

In the **Android Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: I have just added

Comment: please check again..`CrossConnectivity` is a plugin that I got it from `nuget`.

Comment: When are you using these code? After Xamarin.Forms Init ?

Comment: This is a ViewModel method, once click action happens then call this part.

Comment: mmm .. are you sure that is the connectivity plugin? can you comment out all the code except the IsConnected part?

Comment: yes, I am debugging line by line. This class is in the PCL and I have got it `Plugin.Connectivity` from the `nuget`. The code works perfectly fine but whenever I come to that line mentioned in the question, then exception throwing.

Comment: Can you check the value of `CrossConnectivity.Current.IsSupported`  ?

Comment: `Crossconnectivity.Current` only have  `IsConnected, IsRemoteReachable` and `IsReachable`... There is no `IsSupported`.

Comment: yeah, you're right, is CrossConnectivity.IsSupported, my fault

Comment: That returns `false` !

Comment: I am using `Xam.Plugin.Connectivity` by James Montemagno, what should I use?

Comment: Maybe you can create a sample project and upload to test it

Comment: Did you install the plugin in both your PCL and your platform project?

Comment: I only installed it on the PCL.

Comment: Did you ever found the answer ? I have a simular problem, I never return from IsReachable, it waits forever without exception